# VBA Workbooks.OpenText Method Working only on a second run of the code

Tags: vba

Windows 10, Excel 2013.
I'm using the following code to open a text file into excel. The file is coded as UTF-8 and my goal import the text with the special characters (it's in spanish) so i have to "tell" excel that Origin:=65001

```
Sub abrirarchivotexto()
Dim FiletoOpen As String
FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt;*.csv), *.txt;*.csv")
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FiletoOpen, DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=False, Local:=True, Origin:=65001
```

The thing is that if i run the code, it breaks with an '1004' error message for the method Opentext od the object "Workbooks"

Well, i finish the execution of Visual Basic, run the code again, and it works perfectly. I can't understand what changes from the first execution to the second. No idea about why it doesn't work the first time, as it is a code i have seen written in several places with slight modifications.

Here's a [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AxH6cMP7_Fb1psMnRzZFFzZ2M/view?usp=sharing). The first row has special characters.

Any thoughts? Thanks.